# How can I trigger new order email (Customer) after checkout success message in Magento?

Tags: email, magento

I need to remove default new order email in magento. Instead I need to trigger it after receiving success message in onepage checkout.

1. Can I use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event for
   this?
2. How can I disable default new order email trigger?

I have used `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` but i'm receiving empty content. Is this because already the default event is triggered to send order email?

Thanks in advance.